# Testing VueJS method inside of a promise which is returned from a vuex action

Tags: unit-testing, promise, vue.js, vuex, karma-mocha

I have a Vue component, which is using a mapped action from a vuex store, which returns a promise. When the component calls the mapped action, and the mapped action is resolved, I am calling another vue method `vm.$router.push()`. I want to assert that the `push` method gets called. Here is my component, test, and some helper methods I created to sub out the component with vuex and vue-router.

**Here is my `.vue` component with some console.logs to track what's going on.**

```javascript
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="promise" class="click-promise">Promise</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

  export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['promiseAction']),
    promise(){
      const vm = this
      vm.$router.push('/some/route')
      console.log('before promiseAction')
      console.log(vm.promiseAction())
      return vm.promiseAction().then(function (response) {
        console.log('inside promiseAction')
        vm.$router.push('/some/other/route')
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Here is my test. I'm using Mocha, Karma, Chai, and jquery-chia**

```js
import Testing from '@/components/Testing'

describe('Testing.vue', () => {
  const mount = componentHelper(Testing)

  it.only('assert something in a promise returned from an action', () => {
    const promise = new Promise(resolve => resolve('success'))
    const promiseAction = stubAction('promiseAction').returns(promise)
    const vm = mount()
    const routerPush = sinon.spy(vm.$router, 'push')

    $('.click-promise').click()
    expect(promiseAction).to.have.been.called
    expect(routerPush).to.have.been.calledWith('/some/route') //this passes

    return vm.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log('inside nextTick')
      expect(routerPush).to.have.been.calledWith('/some/other/routes') //this never happens
    })
  })
})
```

**And here is my helpers file. I'm not sure if this is 100% neccisary, but I wanted to include everything in this post**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(VueRouter)

let div

beforeEach(() => {
  // create a dom element for the component to mount to
  div = document.createElement('div')
  document.body.appendChild(div)
})

afterEach(() => {
  // clean up the document nodes after each test
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('body *:not([type="text/javascript"])'), node => {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
  })
})

// stub out a store config object
const storeConfig = {
  actions: {}
}

/**
 * Set up a function that will attach the mock store to the component
 * and mount the component to the test div element
 *
 * Use like this:
 * const mount = componentHelper(YourComponent)
 * do some setup
 * call mount() to instantiate the mocked component
 *
 * @param component
 * @returns {function()}
 */
window.componentHelper = function (component) {
  const router = new VueRouter({})
    return () => {
    // 1. attaches the stubbed store to the component
    component.store = new Vuex.Store(storeConfig)
    component.router = router
    // 2. mounts the component to the dom element
    // 3. returns the vue instance
    return new Vue(component).$mount(div)
  }
}

/**
 * Creates an action to be added to the fake store
 * returns a sinon stub which can be asserted against
 * @param actionName
 */
window.stubAction = (actionName) => {
  // 1. create a stub
  const stub = sinon.stub()
  // 2. create the action function that will be placed in the store and add it to the store
  storeConfig.actions[actionName] = function (context, ...args) {
    // 3. when this action is called it will call the stub
    // return the stub so you can assert against the stubbed return value
    // example: stubAction('fakeAction').returns('xyz')
    return stub(...args)
    }
  // 4. return the stub that was placed in the return of the action for assertions
  return stub
}
```

**When I run this test this is what I get.**

```js
LOG LOG: 'before promiseAction'
LOG LOG: Promise{_c: [], _a: undefined, _s: 1, _d: true, _v: 'success', _h: 0, _n: true}

  Testing.vue
    ✓ assert something in a promise returned from an action

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 4 SUCCESS (0.045 secs / 0.018 secs)
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS


=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 31.58% ( 6/19 )
Branches     : 100% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : 0% ( 0/2 )
Lines        : 31.58% ( 6/19 )
================================================================================
LOG LOG: 'inside nextTick'
ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "AssertionError: expected push to have been called with arguments /some/other/routes
/some/route /some/other/routes "

(found in <Root>)'
ERROR LOG: AssertionError{message: 'expected push to have been called with arguments /some/other/routes
/some/route /some/other/routes ', showDiff: false, actual: push, expected: undefined, stack: undefined, line: 210, sourceURL: 'http://localhost:9877/absolute/home/doug/Code/projects/vue-testing-sandbox/node_modules/chai/chai.js?ab7cf506d9d77c111c878b1e10b7f25348630760'}
LOG LOG: 'inside promiseAction'
```

As you can see the test passes, but the code inside of the promise does not run until after the test is done. I'm talking about this section

```
return vm.promiseAction().then(function (response) {
    console.log('inside promiseAction')
    vm.$router.push('/some/other/route')
  })
```

I also logged out the promise function `console.log(vm.promiseAction())`  and you can see it is what you would expect.

How can I get the test to wait for the promise? I thought `nextTick` might be the answer, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a really good way to do what you want via clicking the button. Moreover, I'm not sure it's even really worth testing it through clicking the button. If Vue's event handlers aren't working correctly you have bigger problems.

Instead I would suggest you just call the `promise` method and execute your tests in the success callback of the promise returned from that method.

```
//execute the handler
const test = vm.promise()

// test that the pre-async actions occured
expect(promiseAction).to.have.been.called
expect(routerPush).to.have.been.calledWith('/some/route')

// test the post-async action occurred
return test.then(() => {
  expect(routerPush).to.have.been.calledWith('/some/other/routes')
})
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. The only thing that had to be modified is the `test.then()` had to be returned to the test. `return test.then(() => { //expectation })`

I think it would be nice if there was a way to "click" the button and then assert the `$router.push()` happened after the promise resolves. This is definitely a good solution though.

Comment: @DougSteinberg Glad to hear it :) I'll add the return.